# Proof that equality on categorical products is componentwise equality

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I want to proof that in the categorical product as defined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_%28category_theory%29) it holds that
for $x,y \in \prod X_i$ then
$$
 x = y \textrm{ iff } \forall i \in I : \pi_i(x) = \pi_i(y).
$$
The direction from left to right is trivial, but the other, that iff the components equal than their product is equal I am not able to proof, I tried to substitute the identity morphisms in the universal property, but I always get the wrong "types" in the functions involved. Any hints?

Comment: In what category are you taking the product? The way you describe it, it seems like the product is or has as underlying set the cartesian product, but then two elements are equal by definition when they have the same coordinates.

Comment: Hello, I am not entirely sure what this means, In a general category, there is no notion of membership.

Comment: Yes in Set with cartesian product as realisation of the categorial product they are equal by definition, but that approach seems unsatisfactory for me, or does this property does not hold in arbitrary categories with products...

Comment: Yes, there is no notion of membership! I am confused...

Comment: Ok, so this property is not expressable in a general category?

Comment: @Stefan The closest thing I can think of, is a well-pointed category. But, I don't know what you want.

Comment: @Stefan The projections are epimorhpisms--maybe that's what you want?

Comment: I am not that into to category theory to know well-pointed sets, but yes think I know it not well enough to see that I asked nonsense ;) For you suggestion that the $\pi_i$ are epimorphism, how could this be proofed, at first I thought by using the universal property on the idenity maps, so that $\pi_i \circ f = id_{X_i}$ could be established, but then I saw that I run into trouble because again I get "type errors" that in the universal property the $f_i$ must all came from one set $f_i : Y \to X$...

Comment: The projections of a product need not be epimorphisms. In the category of sets, there are only the trivial counterexamples involving the empty set; the projection from $\varnothing\times A$ to $A$ is not an epimorphism if $A$ is nonempty. But in other categories, even very nice ones like some topoi, there can be other, less trivial counterexamples.

Answer (score 4):

In arbitrary categories, there is a notion of "generalized element": A generalized element of an object $A$ is any morphism into $A$ (from any object of the category). A morphism $A\to B$ can be applied to a generalized element $Z\to A$ just by composing them to get a generalized element $Z\to B$. In these terms, the result you want can be proved: A generalized element of $\prod_iX_i$ is determined by its images under all the projections $\pi_i$. But "proved" here is too grandiose a term; this fact is just part of the categorical definition of product.

Answer (score 2):

As in a general category there is no meaning to membership in an object, one needs to carefully interpret what is meant. The usual way to go about it is to use generalized elements. A generalized element in a category is simply a morphism $fx:A\to B$ in it, just we *think* of it as being an element of $B$ of type $A$. In particular, when $A$ is a terminal object, such generalized elements are called global elements. In familiar categories such as $Set$ or $Top$ but not $Grp$ or $Ring$) global elements $*\to A$ correspond precisely to the actual elements in the underlying set of the object $A$.

Note that if $x:A\to B$ is a generalized element and $f:B\to C$ is a morphism, then defining $f(x)$ to mean $f\circ x$ turns every morphism into a function on generalized elements that preserves types. In particular, every morphism $f:B\to C$ gives rise to a function from the global elements of $B$ to the global elements of $C$.

Now, if $B\prod C$ is a product in the category, then a global element $x$ of it of type $A$ is a morphism $x:A\to B\prod C$, and thus corresponds bijectively and naturally to a pair of morphisms $A\to B$ and $A\to C$. In other words, for each type $A$, there is a natural bijection between the generalized elements of $A$ of the product $B\prod C$ and pairs of generalized elements of type $A$ of each component.